# use udf in sql vs method in C# code in performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, bigdata, performance-testing

hear is my user define function in <"SQL"> Code for validation Personnel code assignment...
per personnel in a time assignment a card-no in time-sheet programs. when run evacuation service, timekeeper info send to this function to validate personnel.
function return valid personnel when just 1 personnel assignment to this card.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPerosnnleBaseIdByCardAndTime]( @Card VARCHAR(100),@Time SMALLDATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
----------------
--DECLARE @Card VARCHAR(100) = '11000'
--DECLARE @Time SMALLDATETIME = '2019-02-01 00:00:00'--GETDATE()
---------------------------------
DECLARE @MaxDate SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @PersonnelBaseId INT
DECLARE @Current int = 0
SELECT 
    @MaxDate = MAX(EffectiveDate) 
FROM 
    dbo.tkp_PersonnelDetails records
    inner join prs_Personnel personnel on personnel.Id = records.PersonnelBaseID AND    
                                                         Personnel.Active = 1    AND 
                                                         Personnel.Deleted = 0   AND
                                                         records.Deleted = 0    
WHERE records.Deleted = 0 AND records.EffectiveDate <= @Time AND CardNo = @Card

SELECT @PersonnelBaseId = PersonnelBaseId, @Current = [Current] FROM dbo.tkp_PersonnelDetails WHERE EffectiveDate = @MaxDate AND Deleted = 0 AND CardNo = @Card 

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tkp_PersonnelDetails WHERE CardNo = @Card AND EffectiveDate <= @Time AND Deleted = 0) = 1)
    RETURN @PersonnelBaseId
--IF @Current = 1 
--  SELECT @PersonnelBaseId
---------
DECLARE @DETAILS TABLE (PersonnelBaseId INT,CardNo VARCHAR(100),EffectiveDate SMALLDATETIME,ROW_NO INT,PERS_NNUMBER INT)
INSERT INTO @DETAILS
SELECT 
     PD.PersonnelBaseId,CardNo,EffectiveDate        
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PD.PERSONNELBASEID ORDER BY EFFECTIVEDATE) AS ROW_NO
    ,DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY PD.PERSONNELBASEID) AS PERS_NNUMBER 
FROM
    dbo.tkp_PersonnelDetails PD 
WHERE PersonnelBaseId in (select PersonnelBaseId from dbo.tkp_PersonnelDetails where CardNo = @Card)
ORDER BY 
    PERS_NNUMBER,ROW_NO
DECLARE @CurrectPersonnelCount int = 0
DECLARE @MaxPersNumber int = 1,@MaxRowNumber int = 1
DECLARE @PersNumber int = 1,@RowNumber int = 1
DECLARE @_PersonnelBaseId int ,@_CardNo varchar(100) ,@_EffectiveDate smalldatetime,@_CardNoNext varchar(100) ,@_EffectiveDateNext smalldatetime

SELECT @MaxPersNumber = max(PERS_NNUMBER) FROM @DETAILS
WHILE @PersNumber <= @MaxPersNumber
BEGIN
    SELECT @_PersonnelBaseId = PersonnelBaseId,@_CardNo = CardNo,@_EffectiveDate = EffectiveDate FROM @DETAILS WHERE PERS_NNUMBER = @PersNumber AND ROW_NO = @RowNumber
    SELECT @MaxRowNumber = max(ROW_NO) FROM @DETAILS WHERE PersonnelBaseId = @_PersonnelBaseId
    WHILE @RowNumber <= @MaxRowNumber
    BEGIN
        IF @_CardNo = @Card and @_EffectiveDate <= @Time
        BEGIN
            SELECT @_CardNoNext = CardNo,@_EffectiveDateNext = EffectiveDate FROM @DETAILS WHERE PERS_NNUMBER = @PersNumber AND ROW_NO = @RowNumber +1          
            IF @_EffectiveDateNext > @Time OR @_EffectiveDateNext IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SET @CurrectPersonnelCount += 1
                SET @PersonnelBaseId = @_PersonnelBaseId
            END                         
        END
        SET @RowNumber += 1
        SELECT @_PersonnelBaseId = PersonnelBaseId,@_CardNo = CardNo,@_EffectiveDate = EffectiveDate FROM @DETAILS WHERE PERS_NNUMBER = @PersNumber AND ROW_NO = @RowNumber
    END
    SET @PersNumber += 1
END
IF @CurrectPersonnelCount = 1
    RETURN @PersonnelBaseId
ELSE 
    RETURN 0

--SELECT * FROM @DETAILS

RETURN 0
END
```

I can write this function in C# but want to find which is the best practice?
use in C# method or "user define functions" in <"SQL"> ?
for big data and little size data

Comment: If you're going to use a user defined function in SQL server, use an inline table-value function; scalar and multi-line table-value functions are both known to perform poorly. If you're using SQL Server 2019, however, you can make use of the inline scalar function abilities.

Comment: why you don't use mapping Personnel-Card-no in separate table?

Comment: Also, a `WHILE` loop is a really bad idea for any SQL; unless you *really* need an iterative task (of which there are few scenarios). You really want to use a set based method.

Comment: @Larnu do you mean if I utilize SQL server 2019 then is non it to in .net? and this problem is not dependent to the scale of data?

Comment: That's not what I said @abbasezoji, no. I said *if you use SQL Server*, not "use SQL Server 2019" (which is still in preview). You wouldn't be able to convert the above to an inline scalar function anyway.

Comment: Thank you  @Larnu for your useful recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use iterative functions frequently, So you are not able to use inline Functions in such situations, then According to this question it's better to handle functions by C# methods.

Comment: This is pretty vague, if I'm honest. There's not enough data here to say that what the OP has would be best in the application. Yes, iteration is better in an application, but then if you *were* to do the logic in the DBMS you shouldn't be using iteration to start with, and a dataset approach should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use inline function According to the top Testimonies. 
Then this function created by `CTE`:

```
;WITH PersonnelDetailsByCarnoAndLessTime AS
(
    SELECT
        PD.*    
    FROM
        tkp_PersonnelDetails PD     
        JOIN prs_Personnel P ON P.ID = PersonnelBaseId AND P.DELETED = 0 AND P.ACTIVE = 1   
        JOIN (SELECT PersonnelBaseId,MAX(EffectiveDate) MAX_EffectiveDate
                FROM tkp_PersonnelDetails PD
                WHERE EffectiveDate <= @Time
                GROUP BY PersonnelBaseId
        ) T ON PD.PersonnelBaseId = T.PersonnelBaseId AND PD.EffectiveDate = T.MAX_EffectiveDate
    WHERE PD.Deleted = 0
), R AS
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        PersonnelDetailsByCarnoAndLessTime PDL
    WHERE CardNo = @Card

), AssignmentCount AS
(
    SELECT
        MIN(PersonnelBaseId) PersonnelBaseId,
        COUNT((CASE WHEN EffectiveDate < @Time THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) AssignmentCount
    FROM 
        R
)
SELECT CASE WHEN AssignmentCount = 1 THEN PersonnelBaseId ELSE 0 END PersonnelBaseId FROM AssignmentCount
```